# What should we do with duplicate questions on SO and here

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I spotted the first question being posted on SO and here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270761/show-related-taxonomy-list-if-created
- [Show related Taxonomy list if created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/644/show-related-taxonomy-list-if-created)

What should we do with those kind of questions?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep rephrasing this question: this is covered in [What are the rules for migrating content from Stack Overflow](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66/what-are-the-rules-for-migrating-content-from-stackoverflow) and [Is it possible to pull Drupal questions from StackOverflow to Drupal Answers?](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-possible-to-pull-drupal-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-drupal-answers).

Comment: @Mark these are completely different issues. Related in some ways yes, but still different. You can't migrate a question that has already been asked here. This had nothing with migration at all. Try to read the question instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer my own question, with my thought on the matter.

I think we should try, when possible, to keep the answers here instead of on Stack Overflow. Since we now are in open beta, we can link to answers posted here to avoid answers by different people on both questions.

Ideally, this should be posted as a comment, to the question. This would also help us promote the site to the users that hang out at the drupal tag on Stack Overflow, which has been discussed already.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case, both the questions have been asked from a user that started to use SO/SE sites, and who registered on SO only 11 days ago.

Generally speaking, I think we should worry about questions that the same user keeps to ask both on drupal.SE and SO. I can understand if a user asks a question on SO while drupal.SE, but if the same user keeps asking the same questions in both the sites, maybe it is better to suggest him to not post the same question in both the sites; both the sites are for developers, and I guess that the answer should not change if given on SO or drupal.SE.

To notice also that there could be a reason why the OP is asking Drupal questions on *Stack Overflow*, and not on *Drupal Answers*: If the questions a user asks about Drupal are just a minimal part of all the questions the same user asks on *Stack Overflow*, then I can see why the user keeps asking them on *SO*.